# Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have bought a few android codes from codecanyon.net they used to work before today without any errors but today with every android project i open i get this message

```
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at 
https://docs.gradle.org/4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error: Could not find or load main class 
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon
```

It started today when i opened my android studio (3.0.1
I have uninstalled and reinstalled to the latest version of android 3.1.2 and i still receive the error.

Ive done some research but i couldnt figure out what to do. this happens with everyone of the projects i open. I even opened android studio with admin privs.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i think I figured it out. my antivirus was blocking it, i had turned off my protection and i got past the error.